# RuntimeError: Error building custom image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

When I use [generate_custom_image.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/blob/master/custom-images/generate_custom_image.py) to create custom dataproc image, it throws this error:

````
  File "dataproc/cloud-dataproc/custom-images/generate_custom_image.py", line 429, in <module>
    run()
  File "dataproc/cloud-dataproc/custom-images/generate_custom_image.py", line 420, in run
    daisy_image_creator.create(args)
  File "/Users/yanzhongsu/Documents/copofi/gitlab/core-spark/dataproc/cloud-dataproc/custom-images/daisy_image_creator.py", line 43, in create
    os.path.abspath(args.daisy_path), workflow_script)
  File "/Users/yanzhongsu/Documents/copofi/gitlab/core-spark/dataproc/cloud-dataproc/custom-images/daisy_workflow_executor.py", line 42, in run
    raise RuntimeError("Error building custom image.")
RuntimeError: Error building custom image.```


The customization-script is as follows:
````

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install numpy==1.15.4
pip install pandas==0.23.4
pip install ujson==1.35
pip install geopandas==0.4.0
pip install lxml==4.3.0
```

```
**daisy** is downloaded from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/compute-image-tools/release/darwin/daisy
```

Answer (score 2):

The project [GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/custom-images](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/tree/master/custom-images) has been moved to [GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-custom-images](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-custom-images), also daisy has become optional. Can you try with the new project?